# Inline onclick with two function calls

Tags: javascript, html

I have a place in my code that appends a bunch of other divs to one parent div. Inside each of these divs there is an image (being used as a button) that when clicked needs to call two functions.
 this would normally be done:

```
 onclick = "alert('hi'); addfriend(username);";
```

but since im appending them Im doing the onclick function in the inline code that im appending see here:

```
.append("<div class = 'scrollable'; style = 'width:100%; height: 30%; text-align: left; background-color: white; border: 1px solid gray; line-height: 0%' >" +
     "<div style = 'float: left; margin-left: 5%'><p style = ' font-size:" +fontSize+"'>" + username + "</p><p style = 'color: gray; font-size:" +subtext+"'>" +wholeName+"</p></div>    **<img style = 'float: right; padding-top: 3%; padding-right: 3%; right: 0; height: 80%;' onclick = 'addFriend('"+username+"'); alert('hi')'  src = 'addfriend.png'>**</div>");
```

I know it looks like a mess and that you shouldnt use inline but if its possible thats what I want to do.

Anyway since its inline I tried to wrap both of the onclick functions in ' ' instead of " " but that doesnt let it read both functions for some reason. Any idea how to fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply escape the `'` and `"` characters inside the string with backslashes, resulting in `\'` and `\"` respectively. You might want to look at moving away from inline attribute event handlers though, they're difficult to maintain.

Comment: Perfect I was trying to escape the "" using &quot or whatever it was and that was not working. And yah its fairly hard to maintain but this is the only spot.

Answer (score 0):

try this..

make one function that accept 2 arguments and place those 2 functions inside it

```
function dummy(uname,toalert){
  addFriend(uname);
  alert(toalert);
}
```

and in your inline

```
onclick = 'dummy(\'"+username+"\',\'hi\')'
```

or try to escape '

```
 onclick = 'addFriend(\'"+username+"\'); alert(\'hi\')'
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it appears that you're using jQuery already (based on your .append() snippet), you might want to consider abstracting that function away from the inline code. Thus, you might end up with something like:

```
$('img').click( function() 
{
    //Not sure where you're getting the username from. $(this).parent()... for all we know?
    var username = $('whatever').val(); 
    addFriend(username);
    alert(username);
}
```

This way, you won't have to add the code to every single img tag.

Hope that helps!